# print the first line of those files in current directory which are having last line with a pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, files

I have multiple log files in a directory and want to print first line of those files which are having pattern `vanished` on last line.

Could it be done with `awk` for `*.logs` having also printed name of the logfile before the first line is printed out?

Answer (score 4):

something like this?

```
for f in *.logs; do tail -n 1 -- "$f" | grep -q vanished && { printf '%s: ' "$f"; head -n 1 -- "$f"; }; done
```

You can also do it with `awk` but it will be less efficient if the files are big, because you will have to read the whole file, not just the beginning and the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this with `awk` only this could probably get you in the right direction:

```
for f in *.log; do awk 'NR==1{ first_line=$0 } END { last_line=$0; print( last_line ~ /varnished/) ? "File: " FILENAME "\n" first_line : "" }' "$f"; done
```

The for loop is probably not necessarily but this is the most efficient way I could find doing it with awk

And thanks to the comments below, now we can let `gawk` do its work as follows:

```
gawk 'FNR==1 {first = $0} ENDFILE {if($0 ~ /varnished/) print substr(FILENAME,3) ":", first}' ./*.log
```

On recent linux systems, `awk` is a symlink to `gawk`. For example, on recent Fedora releases this is the case:

```
# ls -l /bin/awk 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Jul 13 07:55 /bin/awk -> gawk
```

Comment: With a reasonably recent GNU awk you probably *could* avoid the loop e.g. `gawk 'FNR==1 {first = $0} ENDFILE {if($0 ~ /varnished/) print FILENAME ":", first}' *.log`

Comment: That wouldn't work with files names `foo=bar.log` for instance. You can work around it by using `./*.log` and replace `FILENAME` with `substr(FILENAME, 3)`.